# How to download an older version of PyTorch Geometric in Google Colab?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

**Question**: How can I download an older version of PyTorch geometric in google colab?

**Context**: I am trying to use/load a pytorch-geometric graph and am getting the error message: "*RuntimeError: The 'data' object was created by an older version of PyG. If this error occurred while loading an already existing dataset, remove the 'processed/' directory in the dataset's root folder and try again.*" This graph was generated during summer 2021.

I am using PyTorch and the following code to import Pytorch geometric, but am still getting the error when using older versions.

```
#import torch
!pip install torch==1.8.0
import torch
torch.__version__

!pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.8.0+cpu.html
```

I am not sure whether I am using the correct older version of pytorch-geometric (I don't really know how to check whether this is correct). Any insight to would be greatly appreciated:

- How to download older version of pytorch geometric?
- What is causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to downgrade: If G is a graph data object giving this error you can simply convert it as follows.

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data
G = Data(**G.__dict__)
```

Comment: I am trying to run this function (https://github.com/zhichunguo/Meta-MGNN/blob/b76c04057ebbf19e164cb101e8a9b9b758f9f008/loader.py#L134) in a github repository. and getting the same error. how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need it but I just ran into the same problem and here's what I found:

1. It seems like there isn't a compatibility document but you can check the version history [here](https://pypi.org/project/torch-geometric/#history) and find the corresponding release for the one nearest to the time when your pytorch version was released, of course this doesn't guarantee compatibility but I think you have  a pretty good chance?
2. For the additional packages e.g. torch-scatter, you can find the corresponding versions [here](https://data.pyg.org/whl/) and install from the `.whl` files.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem. To downgrade the version of PyTorch-Geometric, you need to be sure that the version of PyTorch, CUDA, Python and PyTorch-Geometric, are compatible with each other.

Here is a Github [issue](https://github.com/AutodeskAILab/Building-GAN/issues/9) that will guide you to install your PyG version. Also, take a look at the previous versions of [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) (depends on the version of CUDA). Python version will also have an impact.